# HttpClient Extension with Eventhandler

Tags: c#, httpclient, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend the HttpClient with an EventHandler.
Is this possible?

I have an Extension on HttpClient as follows:

```
    public static class HttpClientExtensions
    {

        public async static Task<T> GetSomthingSpecialAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string url)
        {
            using var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

               //I have an error and want to raise the HttpClientEventError
                HttpClientErrorEvent(null, new HttpClientErrorEventArgs()
                {
                    StatusCode = response.StatusCode,
                    Message = $"{response.StatusCode } {(int)response.StatusCode }  "

                });
                return default(T);
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            [... ]

        }
   }


    public class HttpClientErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public System.Net.HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

But how do I define the HttpClientErrorEvent?
I tried the following but it is not an extension to a specific HttpClient:

```
public static event EventHandler<HttpClientErrorEventArgs> HttpClientErrorEvent = delegate { };
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that at all? `async/await` was introduced so people would *not* be forced to use events. Imagine having to handle the 3 separate events needed to get a response, read the content and parse it. And, who would raise that event? How would you associate each of those 3 events with the actual request ?

Comment: Besides, an error isn't an event. Your code isn't raising an event, it's trying to use events to return an error message. It's *far* easier to just do that - return the error. Use a result type that allows you to return either a value or error. You can use a tuple for this, eg `(T? value,string? error)`, a record `Result<T>(T? value,string? error)` or create a `Result` class with a `Success` and `Error` subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an event to return errors. For starters, how are you going to identify which request raised which error? You'd have to register and unregister event handlers around each call but how would you handle concurrent calls? How would you compose multiple such calls?

Errors aren't events anyway. At best, you'd have to handle the event as if it was a callback - in which case why not use an actual callback?

```
public async static Task<T> GetSomethingSpecialAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string url,Action<(HttpStatusCode Status,string Message)> onError)
{
...
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        onError(response.Status,....);
        return default;
    }
}

...

var value=await client.GetSomethingSpesialAsync(url,
    (status,msg)=>{Console.WriteLine($"Calling {url} Failed with {status}:{msg}");}
);
```

`async/await` was created so people can get rid of callbacks and events though. It's almost impossible to compose multiple async calls with events, and hard enough to do so with callbacks. That's why a *lot* of languages (C#, JavaScript, Dart, even C++ in a way ) introduced promises and `async/await` to get rid of both the success and error callback.

Instead of calling a callback you can actually return either a result or an error from your function. This is a functional way embedded in eg F#, Rust and Go (through tuples). There are a *lot* of ways to do this in C#:

- Return a tuple with the value and error, eg `(T? value, string? error)`
- Create a record with the value and error
- Create separate Success and Error classes that share a common `IResult<T>` interface

Pattern matching can be used with any option to retrieve either the error or value without a ton of `if` statements.

Let's say we have a specific error type, HttpError.:

```
record HttpError(HttpStatusCode Status,string Message);
```

Using tuples, the method becomes:

```
public async static Task<(T value,HttpError error> GetSomethingSpecialAsync<T>(this HttpClient client,string url)
{
...
    if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return (default,new HttpError(response.Status,....);
    }
}
```

And called :

```
var (value,error)=await client.GetSomethingSpecialAsync(url);
if(error!=null)
{
    var (status,msg)=error;
    Console.WriteLine($"Calling {url} Failed with {status}:{msg}");
...
}
```

Instead of a tuple, we can create a `Result` record:

```
record Result<T>(T? Value,HttpError? Error);
```

Or separate classes:

```
interface IResult<T>
{
    bool IsSuccess{get;}
}

record Success<T>(T Value):IResult<T>
{
    public bool IsSuccess=>true;
}

record Error<T>(HttpError Error):IResult<T>
{
    public bool IsSuccess => false;
}


public async static Task<IResult<T>> GetSomethingSpecialAsync<T>(this HttpClient client,string url){...}

var result=await client.GetSomethingSpecialAsync(url);
```

In all cases pattern matching can be used to simplify handling the result, eg:

```
var result=await client.GetSomethingSpecialAsync<T>(url);
switch (result)
{
    case Error<T> (status,message):
        Console.WriteLine($"Calling {url} Failed with {Status}:{Message}");
        break;
    case Success<T> (value):
        ...
        break;
}
```

Having a specific `Result<T>` or `IResult<T>` type makes it easy to write generic methods to handle success, errors or compose a chain of functions. For example, the following could be used to call the "next" function if the previous one succeeded, otherwise just propagate the "error" :

```
IResult<T> ThenIfOk(this IResult<T> previous,Func<T,IResult<T>> func)
{
    return previous switch
    {
        Error<T> error=>error,
        Success<T> ok=>func(ok.Value)
    }
}
```

This would allow creating a pipeline of calls :

```
var finalResult=doSomething(url)
                .ThenIfOk(value=>somethingElse(value))
                .ThenIfOk(....);
```

This style is called [Railway oriented programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) and is very common in functional and dataflow (pipeline) programming

Comment: Thank you very much, I've learned a lot! Sometimes I just try to find solutions that are too simple.
The reason why I need this event right now is that I get an unauthorized response in a blazor server app. If that happens, I would like to take the appropriate steps without having to do this in every call in the application.
But I now understand why this was the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the handlers in your extension class and do something like this ? Please note this code is not thread safe and need to be synchronized around dictionary and list access !

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<HttpClient, List<Action<HttpClientErrorEventArgs>>> Handlers { get; set; }

    static HttpClientExtensions()
    {
        Handlers = new Dictionary<HttpClient, List<Action<HttpClientErrorEventArgs>>>();
    }

    public async static Task<T> GetSomthingSpecialAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        ////code ....

        //I have an error and want to raise the HttpClientEventError
        HttpClientErrorEventArgs args = null;
        client.RaiseEvent(args);
        return default(T);


        ////code
    }

    public static void AddHandler(this HttpClient client, Action<HttpClientErrorEventArgs> handler)
    {
        var found = Handlers.TryGetValue(client, out var handlers);

        if (!found)
        {
            handlers = new List<Action<HttpClientErrorEventArgs>>();
            Handlers[client] = handlers;
        }

        handlers.Add(handler);
    }

    public static void RemoveHandler(this HttpClient client, Action<HttpClientErrorEventArgs> handler)
    {
        var found = Handlers.TryGetValue(client, out var handlers);

        if (found)
        {
            handlers.Remove(handler);

            if (handlers.Count == 0)
            {
                Handlers.Remove(client);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void RaiseEvent(this HttpClient client, HttpClientErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        var found = Handlers.TryGetValue(client, out var handlers);

        if (found)
        {
            foreach (var handler in handlers)
            {
                handler.Invoke(args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there is not really an event that I can assign to as usual. E.g .: MyhttpClient.RaiseEvent + = myEventHandler;